# How to import values from access database into visualbasic combobox?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to add the FirstName and SecondName together to a combobox dropdown on visual basic so that users can select the name whose information they wish to retrieve from the database, but I cannot figure it out

Any help is appreciated.

```
        myConnection.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDB", myConnection)

    Dim adpt As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()

    adpt.Fill(tbl)

    TxtPatient.DataSource = tbl

    TxtPatient.DisplayMember = "LastName"
    TxtPatient.ValueMember = "PatientID"
    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: You could just build it in your Query `SELECT *, LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS FullName FROM PatientDB` Then set your DisplayMember to FullName